# Translation in data in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and I need some translation of errors in my validation form. Here's the simple code for basic rule that I use:

```
data () {
    return {
        dialog: false,
        noteRules: [
            v => !!v || this.$t('requiredChangesDescription')
        ],
    }
```

This works most of the time, but sometimesit throws error like that:

```
app.js:56344 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of null
  at VueComponent.Vue.$t (app.js:56344)
  at noteRules (app.js:4769)
  at VueComponent.validate (app.js:107053)
  at app.js:107009
```

Can I move this part of code so it doesn't show any error?

Answer (score 0):

`this.$t` isn't available when data gets created, so at the point it is null, just like your error says.

I'd create a method to handle this issue:

```js
data() {
  return {
    mounted: false,
    noteRules: [
      v => !!v || this.translate("requiredChangesDescription")
    ],
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.mounted = true;
},
methods: {
  translate(s) {
    if (this.isMounted) return this.$t(s);
    return "";
  }
}
```

If you need this behaviour in several files, consider creating a mixin instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed props for these,

```
computed: {
  noteRules() {
    return [v => !!v || this.$t('requiredChangesDescription')]
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you're handling really large translations files, you can spread the objects.

So for instance, your translation files look like this,

**translations.js**

```
export const Home = {
  title: 'Home Page Title',
  description: 'Home Page description'
};

export const SomeComponent = {
  title: 'Component Title'
};

export const CompX = {
  title: 'ComponentX Title'
};

export const CompY = {
  title: 'ComponentY Title'
};
```

You can selectively build your computed props to use only the translations you want,

```
computed: {
  copyText () {
    return { CompX: { ...this.$t('CompX') }, CompY: { ...this.$t('CompY') } }
  }
}
```

And use the `copyText` in your template for the bindings.

You'll need the `CompX`, `CompY` wrappers in your computed only if you have repeating `key`s (Example: `title` in our code above) in your translations.js file.

If you have distinct keys, you can just do this;

```
computed: {
  copyText () {
    return { ...this.$t('CompX'), ...this.$t('CompY') }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this in a production app before too and it kinda got out of hand when using lots of translations. Just a fair warning if your app has a lot of $t. This is the way to go though if it's just a few words

Comment: It should still be possible, you can 1. split the translations file based on pages/components and import only what you need + you can also cache computed props if they're not changing

Comment: But that would still mean I'd need to create 20 computed if I had to translate 20 things(?). Your answer is obviously correct, I just feel a little uneasy how well this actually scales when applying it to a larger app

Comment: @Rie - I've updated my answer with how you can do it with a single computed prop.